# Getting a backtrace on Android from native threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk, stack-trace

I am working on a codebase that is not originally my own (the open source ARDrone library by Parrot). I have stripped out unnecessary threads and have isolated a crash to a particular thread, namely the one in charge of streaming video packets from the drone [a Parrot ARDrone 2.0].

I have changed the drone from TCP video output to UDP on a different port. When I load up the android application [AR.Freeflight 2], video streams smoothly for a while, but the application universally crashes with a fatal SIGBUS somewhere from execution in the very long and complex video pipeline. It takes anywhere from 20 seconds to 15 minutes to crash.

I have a signal handler set up on the relevant thread, which can successfully capture the signal. I went through the process of attaching the video input thread to the JVM, and I am able to use a cached global reference to find a Java class with a static method that I made for printing the current thread's callstack (I have tested this both with throwing a new RuntimeException and with Thread.dumpStack()). The reason I went through this arduous process is because the version of bionic that is part of the NDK doesn't have a native backtrace() function that I should be able to call directly from the signal handler; it appears that this method has been shown elsewhere on stackoverflow to work perfectly well to trace the entire C callstack *if you are still in a Java-spawned thread*. However, in my application, the *only* call that shows up as occurring before my static void trace-printing function is

```
dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Thus, I am left without knowledge of how to get the call stack for my android application to find the true location of this crash, because Java is treating everything that happened before the first Java invocation of the thread as "one big blob of C". Does anyone have a way around this?

Update: I managed to extract the android-specific sigcontext object from the void* final argument to my signal handler, which means I now have the instruction pointer and stack pointer from before the signal occurred. In that case, does anyone know how I can call _Unwind_Backtrace to backtrace the call stack from there, instead of unwinding from the signal handler itself?

Answer (score 1):

When an app crashes in native code, you actually get the backtrace logged. Directly after the crash do `adb logcat -d > crash.log`. This crash log doesn't contain any symbols, but the NDK comes with the tool `ndk-stack` for that:

```
ndk-stack -sym <path> [-dump <path>]

   -sym  Contains full path to the root directory for symbols.
   -dump Contains full path to the file containing the crash dump.
         This is an optional parameter. If ommited, ndk-stack will
         read input data from stdin

See docs/NDK-STACK.html in your NDK installation tree for more details.
```

Provided you have the .so files linked without symbols stripped, this will provide a readable stacktrace.

Comment: This is directly contrary to my experience. I am already using the android monitor to observe the crash as it happens, and the log I see in crash.log when I run adb logcat -d > crash.log is merely identical to the one present in the android monitor as the crash happens. The only "crash log" other than the one I generate myself is one where the device's WindowManager informs me that it can no longer look up the window for my application. Perhaps your advice is correct for threads started by the VM, but pthreads started from C code don't seem to be tracked by the JVM at all.

Comment: Basically, I've done more than enough debugging in the past 48 hours to be 99.9% certain that I need a pure C solution.

Comment: The native backtrace is not shown in your IDE, because it is not part of the app section, but the system section. What I usually do is to search for the word backtrace, because this goes to the interesting part. I really don't see a reason why it would be different for your case. We rely heavily on native components in our app and this is how we get a readable trace.

Comment: The android monitor is not an IDE. I am not using eclipse, I am using the monitor in /sdk/tools, with direct access to logcat, which gives me all available debug information about the system as it is running, not merely "the app section". I see every system process output, I see the default signal handler from libc after I'm done with my custom signal handler, I see the windowmanager, everything from system, everything from the dalvikvm service, and when I search crash.log in vim for "backtrace", I see "E486: Pattern not found: backtrace", in a several-thousand-line log of multiple runs.

Comment: I'm sorry if my bug is more obscure than anything you ran into in your "heavy reliance on native components", but you still haven't even confirmed that you *used* native threads. The smart way to develop this codebase would've been to just make them all java-spawned threads in the first place, but like I said, I didn't design it (and replacing them at this point would be suicide). I wouldn't be surprised if your team was smarter about Android threading than these french drone-software developers. But the end result is that your solution is wrong for my application.

Comment: Threads are spawned from Java and from native code. I don't really remember whether only Java spawned threads crashed. Would be curious, but entirely possible. Either way, sorry my answer doesn't help you, but this is how we do it.